# Strict Standards: Non-static method should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Tags: php, static, standards, strict, non-static

This is a question specific to a custom wrote CMS we have taken over. We moved servers and the PHP version changed from 5.3.8 to 5.4.1.
Since then we can't get the CMS to work and are getting this error:

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method Vox_Model_Setting::getMapper() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /var/www/vhosts/ds8760.dedicated.turbodns.co.uk/eera-bioenergy.com/application/modules/users/models/Role.php on line 71
```

Line 71 says:

```
$settings = new Vox_Model_Setting(Vox_Model_Setting::getMapper()->findOne(array('module' => 'users')));
```

Can anyone advise what may be going wrong?

Thanks :)

edit: adding getMapper()

```
    public function getMapper()
{
   if (null === self::$__mapper) {
      self::setMapper(new Vox_Model_Setting_Mapper());
   }
   return self::$__mapper;     
}
```

Comment: Check you `getMapper()` function type . The error says it is not `static` and you are calling it static fashion. You have to create an `object` of  `Vox_Model_Setting`  class prior to call its non-static methods

Comment: Hi,  this is getMapper()

    public function getMapper()
    {
    if (null === self::$__mapper) {
    self::setMapper(new Vox_Model_Setting_Mapper());
    }
    return self::$__mapper;    
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your method type, add the `static` keyword and call as you are doing now.

```
public function getMapper() {
 if (null === self::$__mapper) 
 { 
  self::setMapper(new Vox_Model_Setting_Mapper());
 } 
 return self::$__mapper;    
}
```

to

```
public static function getMapper() { # see extra static keyword
 if (null === self::$__mapper) 
 { 
  self::setMapper(new Vox_Model_Setting_Mapper());
 } 
 return self::$__mapper;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.4 comes with Strict Standards notices active by default, notices that are off by default in 5.3, and were probably ignored (because most ppl. tend to do this, even though is a bad practice).

To quick fix the problem turn them off them (you can use this):

error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);

Or this in htaccess:

php_value error_reporting 30711

Still, I strongly suggest you fix them one by one. The one you specify there can be fixed by adding static to the getMapper() function, but this may affect other parts of your scripts (where it may be called non statically).